# Do not understand why C++ program produces no output

Tags: c++

I am working on Accelerated C++ exercise 3-3 and I cannot for the life of me figure out why my program produces no output. I've even tried adding test couts along the way but it doesn't give me anything. Why won't it produce any output at all when I add a cout statement even outside of the main for loop?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;        using std::cin;
using std::endl;        using std::vector;
using std::sort;        using std::string;

int main() {
    int count = 0;
    string input;
    vector<string> words;
    typedef vector<string>::size_type vec_sz;
    vec_sz size = words.size();

    cout << "Sentence: ";
    while(cin >> input) {
        words.push_back(input);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
            if(words[i] == words[j]) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        cout << "The word " << words[i] << " appears " << count << " times." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You take words size before you append to it, t will be size 0. Move `vec_sz size = words.size();` after the while loop.

Comment: I believe your input code is broken aswell. Put a cout line inside that loop and after it to see what you get. How were you expecting to exit that loop?  As an aside perhaps multi_set is the container that might serve you best since what you are looking for is a counter.

Answer (score 2):

You can check that `size == 0`. So, there are no any iterations in both `for`-loops.

To fix it you need to move the line `vec_sz size = words.size();` few lines lower.

Try this order:

```
cout << "Sentence: ";
while(cin >> input) {
    words.push_back(input);
}

vec_sz size = words.size();
```

Also there is a mistake it logic in your `for`-loops. You need to reset `count` each time (just add `count = 0;` right before internal loop to have correct results).

You can check how it works here: http://ideone.com/T2cPcH (with the mistake with initialization of `count`)

Comment: It means that we need to know something specific about your configuration. You can check that this program produces output: http://ideone.com/T2cPcH

Comment: I am using CLion and there appears to be a strange bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5704

Comment: @JonathanDewein Thank you for this interesting link!

Answer (score 1):

The size variable is read **before** you insert anything into it. Therefore it's value is 0 at the point you read it. If it were to make it to the for loop at the bottom that loop will run no iterations `0 < (0 - 1)` is false.

You can do away with your `size` variable. `vector::size` is a constant time operation. There is no overhead from calling it.

Also I changed how you read lines from the `cin`. Now it will read the line using `std::getline`. The line could have multiple words on one line, so it uses a `stringstream` to read each word out of the line and insert that into the vector.

There is another container called `multiset`, which may suit your needs better in terms of counting words.

An even better way would be to use an `unordered_dict` which can be used to hold a count for each string. It works because when you insert a new entry int the `unordered_map` it's int value will default to 0, so you can safely always apply an increment operation to it.

Examples below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>

// don't do this in a header file!!
using namespace std;

void basic()
{
    string input;
    vector<string> words;

    cout << "Sentence: ";

    if(std::getline(std::cin, input))
    {
        istringstream ss(input);
        string word;

        while(ss >> word){
            words.push_back(word);
        }
    }

    for(const auto& word: words) {
        int count = 0;
        for(const auto& word2: words) {
            if(word == word2) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        cout << "The word " << word << " appears " << count << " times.\n";
    }
}

void better()
{
    multiset<string> ms;
    string input;

    cout << "Sentence: ";

    if(std::getline(std::cin, input))
    {
        istringstream ss(input);
        string word;

        while(ss >> word){
            ms.insert(word);
        }
    }

    for(auto it = ms.begin(), end = ms.end(); 
        it != end; 
        it = ms.upper_bound(*it))
    {
        cout << *it << "'count=" << ms.count(*it) << '\n';
    }
}

void best()
{
    unordered_map<string, int> counter;
    string input;

    cout << "Sentence: ";

    if(std::getline(std::cin, input))
    {
        istringstream ss(input);
        string word;

        while(ss >> word){
            counter[word]++;
        }
    }

    for(const auto& it: counter)
    {
        cout << it.first << "'count=" << it.second << '\n';
    }
}

int main() 
{
    //basic();
    //better(); 
    best();   
}
```